# AlarmManager срабатывает с задержкой

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

AlarmManager срабатывает не в конкретно заданное время, а спустя ~5 минут после заданного времени... Why? А так же срабатывает, если я его активирую по прошедствию времени. То есть, если он установлен на 10:00, и я его активирую в 11:00 то по идее он должен сработать завтра в 10:00, но он срабатывает сеюжеминутно. И сработает завтра в ~10:05

```
   void setMorningAlarm(Context context){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, morningId, intent, 0);
        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                time.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pi);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Morning Notify", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: RTFM setInexactRepeating, setRepeating, set, setExact...

Comment: setRepeating() - задаёт повторяющиеся сигнализации с фиксированным временным интервалом
setInexactRepeating() - устанавливает повторяющиеся сигнализации без строгого требования к точности периода повторения. Этот метод является предпочтительнее предыдущего для экономии ресурсов системы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для точного срабатывания по времени используйте `setRepeating()` вместо `setInexactRepeating`.

По поводу немедленного срабатывания сегодня, если назначенное время сегодня уже в прошлом. Дело в том, что сделав, как описано у Вас в вопросе, например, в 11.00, Вы получаете просроченный `Alarm`, который немедленно выполняется. Так заложено в системе. Чтобы этого избежать проследите, чтобы время срабатывания было в будущем. Если оно уже в прошлом, прибавьте сутки. Например, так:

```
    Calendar timeToFireAlarm = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeToFireAlarm .set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    timeToFireAlarm .set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(timeToFireAlarm.getTimeInMillis < now.getTimeInMillis())
         timeToFireAlarm.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

Comment: Да спасибо. Я как-то так и выкрутился...только у меня вообще срабатывает только на следующие сутки от установленого `alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                time.getTimeInMillis()+ TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pi);`

Comment: Возможно срабатывает через сутки потому что Вы всегда эти сутки прибавляете  ( + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1) ), даже если нужное время сегодня еще не наступило. Если так, то используйте проверку вроде моей.